# Monolithic Haskell projects vs partitioning them into smaller programs

Tags: haskell

In his [Monad Reader article on Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/f/f0/TMR-Issue12.pdf) p.33, Neil Mitchell advocates bundling up Haskell projects into a single executable with multiple modes. (FYI Neil Mitchell's CmdArgs library makes this easy.) So there might be one mode to start a web server, another mode to query the database from the command line, etc. Quote:

> Provide one executable
>
> Version 3 had four executable programs – one to generate ranking
>   information, one to do command line searching, one to do web
>   searching, and one to do regression testing. Version 4 has one
>   executable, which does all the above and more, controlled by ﬂags.
>   There are many advantages to providing only one end program – it
>   reduces the chance of code breaking without noticing it, it makes the
>   total ﬁle size smaller by not duplicating the Haskell run-time system,
>   it decreases the number of commands users need to learn. The move to
>   one multipurpose executable seems to be a common theme, which tools
>   such as darcs and hpc both being based on one command with multiple
>   modes.�

My question: Is it generally considered a best practice in Haskell to put everything in a single larger, monolithic executable instead of, say, following the "Unix philosophy" and building small, independent, interoperating Haskell programs that communicate via database or text streams?

I can see how a large monolithic Haskell program lets you leverage type safety better by sharing core data types throughout the whole system. But the standard warnings against large monoliths still seem to apply, including the increased risk of dependency conflicts.

Comment: You can still get safety benefits by framing everything as a library and having multiple main modules, cabal can even quite easily build them individually.

Comment: Why not both?  Build your application as a series of small, single-mode executables, then have a multi-mode executable that calls each of the single-mode ones.  That way you can use the Unix philosophy of small, composable tools that can all be used through a single interface if you so choose.  Unfortunately this means that you lose some benefits of type checking and you duplicate the runtime in each executable, but you get the best usability of both worlds.

Comment: FYI, [_optparse-applicative_](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) is miles ahead of _cmdargs_.

Answer (score 1):

There have often been many Unix tools that provided complex functionality via sub-commands, and I think that the number of them have been growing lately.

My first example would be the Unix shell. There are several commands that are built-in and various shells build in different sets of commands while leaving others to be implemented as binaries.

Another classic Unix example would be the vi editor. Many implementations provide the functionality of a read-only file viewer (view) as well as a command-based editor (ex) depending on the name by which the binary is invoked. The binary is linked to the filesystem under several names so that the same binary provides all tools.

As a more contemporary example, the git version control package is implemented in a similar way as I described vi, although it has a small set of binaries that are linked as a *much* larger set of names in the filesystem instead of just a single binary. Furthermore, you can invoke the functionality via the individual file names, such as `git-status` and `git-diff`, or you can use a multi-level command via the primary `git` binary, e.g. `git status` and `git diff`.

So I would suggest that this has been an accepted practice even in the Unix world for quite a while, and you should not discard the advice due to conflict with Unix philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the best of both worlds to a certain extent with symbolic links to your executable, and examining ARGV[0] for behaviour.

If there's no need or intention to upgrade such tools separately, then I think putting them in one program is the best approach. I think this applies if the tools are closely related, like what you've mentioned in your example.

This isn't against the unix philosophy, `ls` has a whole raft of options that change it's behaviour that you could theoretically put into separate programs. But they share the common functionality of listing the contents of directories, so it's all in the same executable.

But if the functions are largely separate (i.e. `ls` and `cat`) and could reasonably be upgraded separately, then putting them in separate executables may be appropriate.